# Java - Is it a bad idea to have fully static classes?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, static-access

I'm working on a larger solo project and right now, and I have several classes in which I do not see any reason to create an instance of.

My dice class right now, for example, stores all of its data statically and all of its methods are static too. I don't need to initialize it because when I want to roll the dice and get a new value, I just use `Dice.roll()`.

I have several similar classes that only have one main function like this and I'm about to start working on a sort of "controller" class that will be in charge of all of the events (like when a player moves, and what current turn it is) and I've found that I could follow the same idea for this class. I don't ever plan on creating multiple objects for these specific classes, so would it be a bad idea to make them fully static?

I was wondering if this is considered "bad practice" when it comes to Java. From what I've seen, the community seems to be kind of split on this topic? Anyways, I would love some discussion on this and links to resources would be great too!

Comment: If your program is fully procedural. Why did you choose Java?

Comment: Try writing unit tests for these classes, and you'll figure out why people don't like static methods that access static state.

Comment: @Laiv I'm still kind of new to programming, about a year of C++, I'm taking a Java class this semester and I'm starting to like Java a lot more, the graphics libraries especially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and when should I make a class 'static'? What is the purpose of 'static' keyword on classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103914/why-and-when-should-i-make-a-class-static-what-is-the-purpose-of-static-key)

Comment: Regarding static classes. If static methods are pure (hold no state, have input arguments and a return type). There's nothing to be worried about

Comment: see also: [Make methods that do not depend on instance fields, static?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/215826/31260)

Comment: In addition to Laiv: Not only there is nothing to worry about - those are probably the easiest and most pleasant things to test because they are functional programming: Put something in, get something back, compare it to an expected value and be happy you had no object to set up before.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with static classes that are truly *static*.  That is to say, there is no internal state to speak of that would cause the output of the methods to change.

If `Dice.roll()` is simply returning a new random number from 1 to 6, it's not changing state.  Granted, you may be sharing a `Random` instance, but I wouldn't consider that a change of state as by definition, the output is always going to be well, random.  It is also thread-safe so there are no problems here.

You'll often see final "Helper" or other utility classes which have a private constructor and static members.  The private constructor contains no logic and serves only to prevent someone from instantiating the class.  The final modifier only brings this idea home that this isn't a class you'd ever want to derive from.  It is merely a utility class.  If done properly, there should be no singleton or other class members which are not themselves static and final.

So long as you follow these guidelines and you're not making singletons, there is absolutely nothing wrong with this.  You mention a controller class, and this will almost *certainly* require state changes, so I would advise against using only static methods.  You can rely heavily on a static utility class, but you cannot *make* it a static utility class.

---

What is considered a *change in state* for a class?  Well, lets exclude random numbers for a second, as they're nondeterministic by definition and therefore the return value changes often.

A pure function is one which is deterministic, which is to say, for a given input, you will get one and exactly one output.  You want static methods to be pure functions.  In Java there are ways of tweaking behavior of static methods to hold state, but they're almost never good ideas.  When you declare a method as *static*, the typical programmer will assume right off the bat that it is a pure function.  Deviating from expected behavior is how you tend to create bugs in your program, generally speaking and should be avoided.

A singleton is a class containing static methods about as opposite of "pure function" as you can be.  A single static private member is kept internally to the class which is used to ensure there is exactly one instance.  This is not best practice and can get you into trouble later for a number of reasons.  To know what we're talking about, here is a simple example of a singleton:

```
// DON'T DO THIS!
class Singleton {
  private String name; 
  private static Singleton instance = null;

  private Singleton(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
      instance = new Singleton("George");
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

assert Singleton.getInstance().getName() == "George"
```

Comment: What would you consider a change of state? And what exactly are singletons and why are they bad? From what I've read, singletons are a class that don't allow you to create another instance?

Comment: If I want to test what happens when a double six is rolled, I’m stuck here as you have s static class with a static random number generator. So no, `Dice.roll()` is not a valid exception to the “no global state” rule.

Comment: @HexTeke Updated answer.

Comment: @DavidArno True, but I suppose at that point we're really in trouble if we're testing a single call to `random.nextInt(6) + 1`.    ;)

Comment: @Neil Thank you! Very in depth and exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! I may have to do a bit of editing 

Comment: @Neil, apologies, I didn't explain myself very well. We aren't testing the random number sequence, we are affecting that sequence to assist other tests. If we are testing that eg `RollAndMove()` rolls again when we supply a double six, then the easiest, most robust way to do that is to mock out either `Dice` or the random number generator. Ergo, `Dice` does not want to be a static class using a static random generator.

Comment: Your update hits the issue on the head though: static methods should be deterministic; they should have no side effects.

Comment: Just another thought: static access creates *high couppling*. This is acceptable as long as the code using the satic methods is *closely related* (in the means of the business case).

Comment: @DavidArno I agree with your comment, but it might be worth mentioning that this is Java-specific (perfectly fine, this is tagged after all Java). Other languages (maybe even Java in the future) might be able to inject *functions* in which case having a static method (aka function) that can be injected would sufficient.

Comment: @DavidArno the issue you raised entirely lies on caller side, it's not the fault of Dice. Change caller to utilize dependency injection and use `Supplier<Integer>`. You can supply what you want in tests, while still using `Dice::roll` in "production".

Answer (score 11):

To give an example of the limitations of a `static` class, what if some of your gamers want to get a slight bonus on their die rolls?  And they are willing to pay big bucks!  :-)

Yes, you could add another parameter, so `Dice.roll(bonus)`,

Later you need D20s.

`Dice.roll(bonus, sides)`

Yeah, but some players have the "supremely capable" feat so they can never "fumble" (roll a 1).

`Dice.roll(bonus, sides, isFumbleAllowed)`.

This is getting messy, is it not?

Comment: this seems to be orthogonal to the question, its getting messy whether these are static methods or normal methods

Comment: @jk, I think I understood his point. Does not make sense to have a Dice static class when you think in more types of dices. In that case, we can have different dice objects, modeling them with good OOP practices.

Comment: I see that this is not optimal, but I fail to see how it is worse than `new Dice().roll(...)`. Or even `DiceFactoryBuilder.Build().Create().roll(...)` That has the same problems, no?

Comment: @nvoigt *"I fail to see how it is worse than `new Dice().roll(...)`"* You'r right, that is the same. **But:** the class *using* the `die` (dice is plural...) should not *create* it. It shold get the `die` instance as *constuctor parameter*, as an *injected dependency*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm not disputing that, all I'm saying is that this answer does not actually answer the question, because this kind of scope creep has nothing to do with the method being static or not.

Comment: @nvoigt *"I'm not disputing that"* - Well, I do. The most powerfull feature of an OO language is *polymorphism*. And *static access* effectively prevents us from using that at all. And you're right: `new Dice().roll(...)` has to be concidered *static access* as well as `Dice.roll(...)`. We only benefit if we *inject* that dependency.

Comment: @jk the difference being that `static` messiness happens in __every__ call, and the knowledge needed is required in every call, so it gets globally splashed all over you application.  In an OOP structure, only the constructor / factory need be messy, and the details of that die are encapsulated.  After that, use polymorphism and just call `roll()`.  I might edit this answer to clarify.

Comment: You're right, In that case, you probably need a decorator for your Dice.

Comment: That example looks messy. But there are a lot of good use cases when you want to offer pure functions .

Answer (score 4):

In the particular case of a Dice class I think using instance methods rather than statics will make testing significantly easier.

If you want to unit test something that uses an instance of Dice (e.g. a Game class) then from your tests you can inject some form of test double of Dice that always returns a fixed sequence of values. Your test can check that the game has the right outcome for those dice rolls.

I'm not a Java developer but I think it would be significantly harder to do that with a fully static Dice class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods

Comment: Just for the records: In Java we have *PowerMock* to replace static dependencies by manipulating the byte code. But using it is just a surrender to bad design...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually known as the **Monostate pattern**, where every instance (and even a "no-instance") is sharing their status. Every member is a class member (i.e., no instance members). They're commonly used to implement "toolkit" classes that bundle a set of methods and constants related to a single responsibility or requirement but don't need a state in order to work (they're purely functional). In fact, Java comes with some of them bundled (for instance, [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)).

A bit off-topic: I rarely agree with the naming of keywords in VisualBasic, but in this case, I think `shared` is certainly clearer and semantically better (it is *shared* among the class itself and all of its instances) than `static` (remains after the lifecycle of the scope it's declared in).